# How to create an R function that takes two inputs?

Tags: r, list, function, variables, input

I've been assigned a homework problem that asks:

```
Write a function called numeric_summary which takes two inputs:\
`x`: A numeric vector\
`group`: A factor vector of the same length as x
```

```
and produces a list as output which contains the following elements:\
`missing`: The number of missing values in x\
`means`: The means of x for each level of groups.\
`sds`: The standard deviations of x for each level of groups\
`p.value`: The p-value for a test of the hypothesis that the means across the >levels of groups are the same (versus the two-sided alternative)\
`is.binary`: Set to FALSE for for this function
```

At the moment I am not concerned with creating the list of outputs, but I am unsure how to code the two input aspect, especially with them being two different types. There is an example given:

```
#numeric_summary <- function(x, group){} 
#
# for example:
#numeric_summary(titanic4$age, titanic4$pclass)
```

I assume that the function should work for any assigned and x and group so my difficulty lies in making that aspect modular or so to speak. The packages used are `tidyverse`, `PASWR`, and `knitr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function like

```
numeric_summary <- function(x, group) {
       #Count missing values
  list(missing = sum(is.na(x)), 
       #Mean by group
       means = tapply(x, group, mean),
       #SD by group 
       sds = tapply(x, group, sd))
}

numeric_summary(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$cyl)
#$missing
#[1] 0

#$means
#    4     6     8 
#26.66 19.74 15.10 

#$sds
#    4     6     8 
#4.510 1.454 2.560
```

Comment: thanks you! quick question, why are we using the function tapply instead of just apply?

Comment: @GianBatayola Because `apply` doesn't take into consideration the groups in calculation. It performs the calculation row-wise or column-wise.